# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException · String resource ID #

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I get this error:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException · String resource ID #0x2040003

and in the full stack I saw that it depends on:

```
Resources.java:322android.content.res.Resources.getText
```

I know probably the error is that I call somewhere a `setText` not passing a string.

My problem is that I do not know where the problem occurs.
Technically the line of the error is this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web, container, false); // <-- HERE IS THE ERROR
}
```

The layout file is:

```
<WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.WebFragment" />
```

I do not know howto find the line code where the error occurs.

Comment: Crash log would be better to look. Add here

Comment: Where can I found it? I get this error from bugsnag

Comment: There is no String resource being used in what you posted, so please post all information, not just what you think matters.

Comment: Here way I am asking: I do not see any string resource can throws the error.

Comment: Please run your code in Android Studio, reproduce the crash and post the errorlog here

Comment: I will try: the problem is that I have many users and just one got this error. I do not know where start to find the error

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141132133 regarding Webview.

It happened to me as well, in my case it's MarkdownView which extends Webview. Apparently upgrading android appcompat library solve the issue, but still, I'm hoping for another solution for current library version.

Because I use the element which caused crash in 2 different place (with same implementation) and it only crash in 1 of them. I've been spending my time searching about this and still dunno why and how to fix it.